# too short FB accessToken in Kinvey _socialIdentity using kinvey-nativescript-sdk

Tags: facebook, nativescript, access-token, kinvey

I have working log-in process with Facebook using Kinvey MIC in my NativeScript app. I am able to log-in into the Kinvey and _socialIdentity record is successfully created. Due to the fact that I need to know also user's email registered with FB account (that is not sent in basic User response from FB), I need to query  FB Graph API for that.

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token= +  accessToken

If I use a accessToken stored in Kinvey's _socialIdentity, FB returns:
"error": {
JS:     "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
JS:     "type": "OAuthException",
JS:     "code": 190,
JS:   }

If I use accessToken generated by FB developers tool and hardcode it into my NS code, everything works well - I receive all requested info.

The difference I found is length of the accessToken:
accessToken stored in Kinvey has 40 characters but the one generated by FB tools has 247 characters.

Could somebody explain why FB accessToken in Kinvey's _socialIdentity is short/impossible for further use or how to get a valid accessToken using kinvey-nativescript-sdk? 
Also if somebody achieved to get an user's contact email from FB account using kinvey-nativescript-sdk.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us some code, how exactly you are retrieving the FB token?

Comment: accessToken = response.data._socialIdentity.kinveyAuth.idp_access_token;   http.getJSON(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=" +
              accessToken
          )
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });

Comment: This works fine now, as Bilger recommended adding an additional Allowed Attributes in Kinvey MIC set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding `client_token` to the *Allowed Attributes* section of the Mobile Identity Connect service configuration?

That will create a new attribute on the `kinveyAuth` object (that is contained in the `_socialIdentity` attribute of the User entity), which will hold the access token that you are talking about.

Can you try that, and let me know if it works?

Edit: You can also try adding `idp_access_token` to the *Allowed Attributes* section. That will directly create an attribute to the `kinveyAuth` entity, which will hold **only** the needed token.

Comment: Bilger, that works perfectly! Adding client_token as suggested will add a \"access_token\", ",\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"expires_in\" attributes into the client_token part of the _socialIdentity in Kinvey`s User collection. An idp_access_token works exactly as described. Thanks!